# How do I prevent user to not to give an input in a specific location? (bash)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I write a basic script to test something. Let's imagine I want to display the lines below (for no good reason):

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    echo -e " _____________________________________"
    echo -e "|_____________________________________|"
    echo -e "|_____________________________________|"
    echo -e "|_____________________________________|"
    echo -e "|_____________________________________|"
    echo -e "|_____________________________________|"

    read -p "Type a letter: " letter
done
```

If I use the program normally, say give an input `a` the output:

```
user@DESKTOP:/mnt/c/Users/user/Documents$ ./script.sh
 _____________________________________
|_____________________________________|
|_____________________________________|
|_____________________________________|
|_____________________________________|
|_____________________________________|
Type a letter: a
 _____________________________________
|_____________________________________|
|_____________________________________|
|_____________________________________|
|_____________________________________|
|_____________________________________|
Type a letter:
```

But if I gave an input to the terminal VERY fast, I break the art like that:

```
user@DESKTOP:/mnt/c/Users/user/Documents$ ./script.sh
a
 _____________________________________
|_____________________________________|
|_____________________________________|
|_____________________________________|
|_____________________________________|
|_____________________________________|
Type a letter:  _____________________________________
|_____________________________________|
|_____________________________________|
|_____________________________________|
|_____________________________________|
|_____________________________________|
Type a letter:
```

I tried with `\n` before `------`, it's worked. But it will be some cases that, I shouldn't use `\n`

How do I prevent this? Thank you!

Comment: You can't prevent that _reliably_. It's not bash which is echoing back the `a` you typed, but the tty driver. You just can't prevent the user from typing something before you echo those lines.

Comment: I see, thanks for the answer. So I can't prevent the input, but any ideas how to prevent the line corruption?

Comment: there's no line corruption; the user typed `a <Enter>` which has been echoed back by the terminal as `a <CR> <LF>` before you printed your ascii art. If you put an `echo` before it, you'll have an extra newline, even when it's not necessary.

Comment: Tried. But this time ```a<Enter>``` broke the middle of the printed art, not first line :(

Comment: For that you could probably try putting all the lines in a single string with embedded newlines. Or something like `printf '%s\n' ' --- ...' '|---...' ...` (you put a command over multiple lines with a `\\` before the newline).

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    stty -echo
    echo -e " _____________________________________"
    echo -e "|_____________________________________|"
    echo -e "|_____________________________________|"
    echo -e "|_____________________________________|"
    echo -e "|_____________________________________|"
    echo -e "|_____________________________________|"
    read -t .1 -n 100 buf
    stty echo
    read -e -i $buf -p "Type a letter: " letter
done
```

Comment: Thanks your answer, but I don't get it. What does ```read -t .1 -n 100 buf``` section do exactly?

Comment: it reads max 100 char in 0.1 sec which was maybe typed while the "art" was drawn

Comment: So what is the purpose of reading ```buf``` while we read ```letter``` already? Is it about read ```-e``` and ```-i``` options? I don't know what they do...

Comment: if you don't read the buffered but not echoed chars into $buf, you won't see this chars but they will be added to the letter just try it.